# Why does React fail to define 'App' component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I made simple Reactjs that has index.js and App.js. App.js defines App component. index.js imports App.js and uses App component. However, index.js receives "App is undefined error". How can this be?

index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import '../components/App.js';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Welcome to donghwankim.com!</p>
      <p>Powered by Gatsby</p>
      <App />
    </div>
  )}
}
```

It imports App.js:

```
/*global kakao*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/App.css';

class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=ee494d4410cf578c0566203d2f487eb9";
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        script.onload = () => {
            kakao.maps.load(() => {
                let el = document.getElementById('map');
                let map = new kakao.maps.Map(el, {
                    center: new kakao.maps.Coords(523951.25, 1085073.75)
                });
            });
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" id="map"></div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and it gives the following error during development:

> 12:8  error  'App' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

From what I learned, shouldn't imported App.js define App? Why is it undefined?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for including the code that causes the problem...and not including everything else. So often people go one way or the other. :-D The above is (IMHO) exactly right.

Comment: Thank you. Was worried because the question is too simple and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
import '../components/App.js';
```

...doesn't actually import anything, it just runs the code in `App.js`. To import the default export, you do so explicitly:

```
import App from '../components/App.js';
//     ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
```

You may now be wondering: "But why doesn't importing `App.js` and running its code create `App` automatically?" Because modules don't create globals (not unless you go out of your way to do so)., and there are no automatic imports. One of the key aspects of modules is that you *explicitly* define the links between them. One benefit of doing that is that when you're using a library with lots of functionality exported by a single module, the browser (or your bundler) can *tree-shake* it — keeping only the parts you actually use, and discarding the rest (the dead wood that fell out when it shook the tree).

Comment: Thank you! Such a quick response.